# Simulated annealing - why when encountering a lower energy state we move to it with probability 1?

Tags: gradient-descent

I'm doing simulated annealing, following a recipe I have -

1. Compute the energy of current state and a neighbor state.
2. If the energy of the neighbor is lower - move to neighbor.
3. If not - move to neighbor with probability $e^{-\Delta/\tau}$ where $\Delta$ is the difference between new energy and old energy.

This seems a bit arbitrary to me. Why not compute the exponent for both the current state and the neighbor, and then just move/stay with these probabilities? This means using a sigmoid, which is derived by dividing the exponent of one of the options with the sum exponents of the two: So the probability to move is $e^{-E1/\tau} / e^{-E1/\tau} + e^{-E2/\tau}$ which can also be written $1 / e^{-\Delta/\tau}$

Comment: You do not describe [simulated annealing](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimulatedAnnealing.html). The correct algorithm moves to *higher* energy states with certain small probabilities (which get smaller as the "temperature" decreases). Your description is merely a slowed-down version of a randomized gradient descent.

Comment: In my description - it does move to higher energy states with certain small probabilities, the issue here is whether or not it can stay even if the neighbor energy is lower.

Comment: Please, then, change your title, which directly contradicts what you just said.

Comment: It does not contradict anything. When encountering a lower energy state, the recipe states that the system will move to it. But I can see the confusion so I'll rephrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete explanation but probably better than none:

In short - The original SA recipe is like so because of the proof of convergence.

In more details - the SA process is a markov process. This process has to be a reversible one for the proof that shows the algorithm converges (this has a clear definition and is equivalent to satisfying something called the detailed balance equations http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detailed_balance#Reversible_Markov_chains).

In order to satisfy this condition the probability to move between states was chosen as in the recipe above.

Some more intuition as to why the alternative I'm offering, the sigmoid, is not right here: The partition function (the normalization element in the equation) is not the sum over the two neighboring states, but instead the sum of all states and their energy values - which is usually incalculable).